# Keep results when click a button

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have a code that generates random numbers when click a button, I want to keep some results from the random numbers and I made a for cycle, to when click in a button it keeps the result but it is not working can someone identify the error.

Thanks.

HTML

```
<button onclick="Generate()">Generate</button>
<button onclick="Keep()">Keep Result</button>

G: <a id="generated"></a>
Keep: <a id="keep"></a>
```

JS

```
function Generate() {

    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    document.getElementById("generated").innerHTML = r;
  }
function Keep() {

    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){

    new_string = r;
  }
    document.getElementById("keep").innerHTML = new_string;
}
```

Comment: `letters` variable is global or undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look up and read about variable scoping in javascript.  The variable `r` is defined with the function `Generate()` and so it doesn't have a value inside of `Keep()`.  At the same time, `Keep()` refers to `letters` which doesn't seem to be defined in your example.  If all you want to do is save the value that was generated why are you looping through things.  Or is this supposed to append the value to a list?  The loop doesn't seem to serve much purpose anyway as all it does it assign a value over and over again.

If all you are trying to do is save the random value displayed, why not just get the inner html and use it.

```
function Keep() {
    new_string = document.getElementById("generated").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("keep").innerHTML = new_string; 
}
```

If you want to append the value to the list each time the button is clicked you can do like this:

```
function Keep() {
    new_string = document.getElementById("generated").innerHTML;
    old_string = document.getElementById("keep").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("keep").innerHTML = String(old_string) + String(new_string); 
}
```

I cast each value to a string to ensure that you don't accidentally end up adding two numbers together.

Comment: Thanks I want to keep a result every time the button keep is pressed but I dont want to keep all results. Your post helped a lot !